# Zabbix and time series data

Tags: c#, .net, device, zabbix

We should monitor and log ~1000 devices (1..4 sensor per device). SMS and email alert and the common functions are required if anything going wrong.

I think we instead of developing the whole ecosystem in .NET/C# it would be nice to use an existing one - for example [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/presentation.php). But is it possible without any bigger hack?

I think that the main problem is that the devices are old-school and using RS232 for communication.

Any idea or any other flexible monitoring software?

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix is a good monitoring tool, and it's easy to configure sms and email alerts. You'll need to script the serial port check, as there is no built in support for that. This may help: http://ramblings.narrabilis.com/node/310